# Error Cannot read property '1' of null while building ionic android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am very new to Ionic Cordova applications. I am trying to build my ionic application for android platform using the following command --

```
ionic cordova build android
```

But it always fails with the following error

```
ERROR building one of the platforms: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Cannot read property '1' of null
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
```

I am having the following configuration --

```
JDK 10.1, Cordova 6.0, Ionic 3
```

Comment: You probably need to upgrade cordova...

Comment: @SurajRao - Hi Suraj, Thanks for the reply. I upgraded cordova and now that error is gone. Its now throwing a new error as follows
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\AmAnand\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
(node:15660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
(node:15660) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: You need to use JDK 1.8 not 10 for cordova currently

Comment: @SurajRao - Thanks Suraj, I will install it right away to see if this works

Answer (score 0):

Your cordova version is old.
The current version is [8.0.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md).
You will need to update this cli package.

Secondly, cordova can only use JDK 1.8. You will have to install this version and set JAVA_HOME accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with parsing output of `java -version`. What I needed was a working installation of OpenJDK v8. Double-check that you can run it and you had no problems with libc (e.g. resulting from installing a package from a different distro).